# Two more tickets please. チケットは or チケットを?

Tags: grammar

チケットは後二枚ください　or チケットを後二枚ください or something else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

チケットを後二枚ください is the default choice. You can use は when there is a contrast (e.g., パンフレット**は**要りませんがチケット**は**あと2枚ください).